# Formula for sample size for hypothesis test for difference in proportions confusion

Tags: sample-size, proportion, statistical-power, group-differences, differences

For a hypothesis test for difference in proportions:

Source A (some Stanford professor):
The sample size for both groups is

$$\frac{2\bar{p}(1-\bar{p})(Z_\beta+Z_{\alpha/2})^2}{(p_1-p_2)^2}$$

$$\bar{p}=\frac{p_1+p_2}{2}=p$$

Source B:
Peter Dalgaard from R Stats package argues the sample size is

$$\left(\frac{\Phi_{\alpha/2}\sqrt{2\bar p(1-\bar p)}+\Phi_\beta\sqrt{p_1(1-p_1)+p_2(1-p_2)}}{|p_2-p_1|}\right)^2$$

Which calculation for the sample size $n$ is more correct, or are they derived using different assumptions?

Comment: Roughly speaking, the first formula is betting that effect size $\Delta = |p_1-p_2|$ is sufficiently small that $\bar p$ can be used for both significance level and Type II error.